# Classically permitted position values in a quantum harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-chemistry

In  a quantum harmonic oscillator that is in the state with quantum number $n$, what range of the position $x$ is allowed classically? Does it have something to do with Bohr's correspondence principle?

Comment: When you diet "classically" does that mean usually or according to classical mechanics?

Answer (score 4):

Assume for a minute that instead of having a quantum oscillator with total energy $E$ you had a classical one with the same amount of energy. That energy is the sum of potential and kinetic contributions:

$$E = E_\textrm{p}+E_\textrm{k}.\tag{1}$$

$E_\textrm{k}$ is zero and the total energy equal to the potential energy when the extension (amplitude) is at a maximum, when

$$E = E_{\textrm{p,max}} = \frac12 kx_\mathrm{max}^2\tag{2}$$

which, solving for $x_\mathrm{max},$ leads to

$$x_\mathrm{max} = \sqrt{\frac{2E}{k}}.\tag{3}$$

All that is left to do is to substitute in the right value for $E.$ That is dictated by the [expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator) for the quantized system,

$$E_n = h\nu\left(n + \frac12\right),\tag{4}$$

so that the corresponding classical maximum amplitude is

$$x_\mathrm{max} = \sqrt{\frac{h\nu(2n + 1)}{k}}.\tag{5}$$

Comment: Thanks @Buck Thorn.  To others, am a first time user of Stack Exchange, without any prior experience. Oindly understand my situatiom